# Concatenate in pyton

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-concatenation

I want to store below syntax in python database where value given with k will increase as per the index value. however this syntax not working. Can anyone suggest

```
DATA_LY["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K1,CY!K1,1,0),1,0)
DATA_LY["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K2,CY!K2,1,0),1,0)

for i,each in enumerate(DATA.index+1,start=1):
     DATA["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K"+"%s"%(i)+",CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Python database". What is *DATA* ?

Comment: I mean dataframe

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest use of a Dataframe. Also, why are you assigning different values to the same location. You'll only ever overwrite any previous assignments. What is *DATA* ?

Comment: The dataframe has 37000 rows and for each row i want to change value given below along with K. DATA_LY["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K1,CY!K1,1,0),1,0)
DATA_LY["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K2,CY!K2,1,0),1,0)

Comment: What is *DATA* ? Without knowing what that looks like this is an impossible question. Your use of *enumerate* is highly dubious

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the syntax in a database, you can use a string variable to hold the value of the syntax and then store that variable in the database.

```
syntax = 'DATA_LY["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K%s,CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)"'

for i, each in enumerate(DATA.index+1,start=1):
    DATA["Matchup"] = syntax % i
```

It then uses a for loop to iterate over the index of the ***DATA DataFrame*** and assigns the value of ***syntax % i*** to the "***Matchup***" column of each row. The **%** operator is used to substitute the value of ***i*** into the string.

Comment: Thanks you @karim Baidar. however the its giving the last number DATA_LY["Matchup"]="=IF(VLOOKUP(K18567,CY...

Comment: That's because all assignments are to the same key so DATA_LY["Matchup"] will only ever have the last value from the loop

Comment: If you want to assign different values to each row, you can modify the code as follows: syntax = '=IF(VLOOKUP(K%s,CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)'

for i, each in enumerate(DATA.index+1,start=1):
    DATA.loc[each,"Matchup"] = syntax % i

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the target dataframe already exists and has some content then:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

# create a dataframe containing one column (fruit) and 3 rows
DATA = DataFrame({'fruit': ['banana', 'apple', 'pear']})

for i in range(DATA.shape[0]):
    DATA.loc[i, 'Matchup'] = f'=IF(VLOOKUP(K{i},CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)'

print(DATA)
```

**Output:**

```
    fruit                          Matchup
0  banana  =IF(VLOOKUP(K0,CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)
1   apple  =IF(VLOOKUP(K1,CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)
2    pear  =IF(VLOOKUP(K2,CY!K:K,1,0),1,0)
```